# Ajax (calling web service) with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, web-services

I have an asp.net mvc application and i need to to use ajax in this application , i need to add a scriptmanager and add a service refrences with the path of a web service and then call the web service from  tag .
I have the following code and it doesn't see the web service :

```
<form>
<input id="SubmitBtn" type="button" value="Sumbit" onclick="TestService(); return false;" />
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/MVCService.asmx" />
    </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    function TestService()
    {
        alert('Welcome');
        var ret = MVCService.HelloWorld(OnCheckComplete,OnFailed,OnTimeOut);
    }
    function OnCheckComplete(arg)
    {
         alert(arg);
    }
    function OnFailed(arg)
    {
        alert(arg);
    }
    function OnTimeOut(arg)
    {
        alert(arg);
    }
     </script>
</form>
```

And it reports an error say : MVCService is undefined
so how can i solve this problem ?
do i need specific configuration in the MVC application to solve this problem ?
I have add ajax toolkit dll to my application refrences and the problem still exist

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks every one i have found the soltuion for the problem at the folloiwng link :
[Ajax with asp.net mvc](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/using-asp-net-ajax-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

The following part solved my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
function TestService() 
{  
   Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke("../../Services/MVCService.asmx","HellowWord", false,null, success, fail );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please say what part of that link solved your problem, so everyone will know.

Comment: Hope that this will be usefull for every one new in MVC ajax or nin MVC at all

Answer (score 2):

Just putting the jQuery solution out there if you want to switch to jQuery:

```
function TestService()
{
    alert('Welcome');

    $.ajax({
        url: "MVCService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json"
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Take sure you have

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
    [ScriptService]
public class MVCService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public DateTime HelloWorld()
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: where to put this jquery code ? in which place in my code i have wrote the full code of the view so can u tell me where to pu this code in order to call web service?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add controls with viewsate in a MVC.NET page?

ScriptManager needs to be in a form runat="server" i think.

Comment: I am putting the form tag with runat="server" and not working

Answer (score 0):

Or - you can use a regular controller action for this.

If

> "foo/bar"

route is configured to

> controller="foo", action="bar"

then

```
$.get("foo/bar", data, callback, "html")
```

with jQuery will call it.