# talking between Web services and MVC Framework

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am new to MVC and Web Services.
According to my project, I have to show listing data at ViewLayer.
The listing data which I have to show will come from other region via its web service server.
It means that I have to communicate with these web server which is separate with my web application server.
Moreover, my web application have to update some of the data and send this updated data to there web service server again.
That is my project requirement.

So I have searched every possible solutions. 
Then I found [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273094/ajax-calling-web-service-with-mvc) at stackoverflow.com. 
According to this, I found that I need to use `$.ajax { url: ... }` style which I think I need to fully rely on view layer.

Then I had found [another](http://hugoware.net/blog/combining-webservices-with-mvc) solutions which I think I need to fully rely on Controller Layer. I mean I have to write all the code which need to talke with web services only at controller layer.

As I am junior to MVC, I could not decide which one is suitable for me.
Every suggestion will be really appreciated and welcome your any suitable solutions more.

Comment: Be more specific about what you are asking and you will get better answers. Both your approaches will work, but if you don´t have any jquery ajax experience that it a quite complicated solution if you are using web services with the SOAP protocol.

Comment: @Glenn, Yes, I see both way will work. But as I am junior, I would like to get some Links or any references to go more detail.

Comment: Like an example for working with $.ajax and web service in View layer or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

As with all things development - it depends!

**If you own the services**, they hang off of the same domain, and you're mostly focused on rendering the results of the web service call to HTML, the client-side AJAX calls work well.

If they're on [a different domain](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj) (or even subdomain), or **you want to do more than "just call" the service** (e.g., clean up the response, add some tracking, transform it in some way) then handling the web service call via the controller is probably the way to go.  You can also easily add server-side caching and logging with this option.

Comment: As an aside - I would definitely not recommend using the server-side controller approach described in that link.  If you're using SOAP, just use Visual Studio to add a service reference off of the service endpoint.  You can dependency-inject that client into your controllers.  Method reflection with string names / XML serialized results is going to be awful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Unobtrusive Ajax Helpers in MVC3
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html